# How to connect to an On Premise JIRA instance in Azure Logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, jira-rest-api

Can you please point to some examples to connect to an **on-premise JIRA instance from logic apps**.

I understand that the **JIRA connector** is only for the cloud hosted endpoints.

The onprem hosted version doesnt have `API-Tokens` associated.

Comment: strange that someone had voted down.

Comment: I have got this working by exposing the JIRA on premise API on API management which made it accesible via logicapps. Hope this helps someone looking for a similar requirement

Comment: Hello @Ujjwal Devarapalli   what Authentification did you  use ? 
any exemple ?

Comment: Hi, this worked for me <authentication-basic username="myusername" password="mypwd" />